# Looping inside a loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm practicing my while loop and general looping skills and have encountered a problem that has left me puzzled.

I'm trying to write a program that gives a price for a movie ticket based on the age of the user. The outer loop and first input statement handles the age to price part. After the user enters their age and a price gets returned for the first input, in the outer loop, they get asked using a second input in the inner loop if they have someone else who's attending. If the user answers no, I'm expecting the entire program to break. If the user answers yes, I'm expecting just the inner loop to break and the first loop to start again. If the user enters anything other than no or yes, I'm expecting the inner loop to start again.

The problem is in the second input statement in the inner loop when I enter 'no'. I'm expecting the entire program to break as it should for 'no', however, just the inner loop breaks which restarts the first loop.

```
while True:
    
    age = input("Enter your age and the price of the movie will be displayed: ")
    if age == 'quit':
        break
    elif int(age) < 3:
        print("You're ticket price today is free.")
       
    elif int(age) < 12:
        print("You're ticket price today is $10. ")
    elif int(age) <= 150:
        print("You're ticket price today is $15")
    elif int(age) > 150:
        print("You've entered an invalid input. Please enter a valid age or type 'quit' to exit.")
    else:
        print("You've entered an invalid input. Please enter a valid age or type 'quit' to exit.")
        
    while True:
        repeat = input("Do you have someone else who's attending this movie? (yes/no): ")
        if repeat.lower() == 'no':
            break
        elif repeat.lower() == 'yes':
            break
        else:
            print("You've entered an invalid input. Please enter 'yes' to add someone or 'no' to quit.")
```

##Update 2

```
flag = True
while flag:   

  
    while True:
        
        age = input("Enter your age and the price of the movie will be displayed: ")
        if age == 'quit':
            break
        elif int(age) < 3:
            print("You're ticket price today is free.")
           
        elif int(age) < 12:
            print("You're ticket price today is $10. ")
        elif int(age) <= 150:
            print("You're ticket price today is $15")
        elif int(age) > 150:
            print("You've entered an invalid input. Please enter a valid age or type 'quit' to exit.")
        else:
            print("You've entered an invalid input. Please enter a valid age or type 'quit' to exit.")
        
        
        while True:
            repeat = input("Do you have someone else who's attending this movie? (yes/no): ")
            if repeat.lower() == 'no':
                flag = False 
                break
            elif repeat.lower() == 'yes':
                break
            else:
                print("You've entered an invalid input. Please enter 'yes' to add someone or 'no' to quit.")
```

Comment: There is no outer loop

Comment: Fix your code indentation so that the outer loop is actually displayed.  Currently it's above the code, included in the question text.

Comment: `break` only stops the closest surrounding loop.  It does not stop **every** loop.

Comment: If you can move your loop to a function, you can use a `return` as a break from the inner loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a flag variable as the outermost while condition, instead of `while True`.

```
flag = True
while flag:
    # do stuff
    while True:
        # do stuff
        if somecondition:
            # set flag=False so the outer loop will stop
            flag = False
            break
```

Comment: Unfortunately this also did not work. When I edited the code the break after the flag = false causes the entire program to restart. When I just had flag = false without the  break I was able to get the entire program to not repeat though. However, it just kept repeating the second input.

Comment: @EM284 "causes the entire program to restart" This sounds like your code has some additional outer loop or function call that you did not show us.

Comment: Please see ##Update 2 in the original post for the changes I made. I'm still new to stackoverflow so forgive me for not being able to put the Update 2 comment, the flag = True  block and the while flag: block in the code.

Comment: @EM284 You should have **changed** the existing outermost `while True` loop to be `while flag:`, instead of adding `while flag:` as a brand new outermost loop.  Because now you have three nested loops, instead of two.

Comment: Ahhh I see. I didn't realize I had three nested loops but that makes so much sense why it would not work. Thank you so much, the new changes work now!